# EventID 1196 | SQL Cluster & FailoverClustering

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I have Pre-Staged the SQLCluster objects, since login had no Domain admin rights.
Later SQL Cluster installation completed successfully.(Also tested with failover and failback).It is working fine till date.

But I am receiving error in event log of failover cluster, that Cluster resources failed registration of one or more associated DNS name(s).

Can anybody explain its impact?

Require help to understand below error.

```
**
Cluster network name resource 'SQL Network Name (servername)' failed 
registration of one or more associated DNS name(s) for the following reason:
DNS operation refused.
**
```

Answer (score 0):

From [How to fix Hyper-V Cluster error 1196: Cluster Name failed registration](https://www.itworld.com/article/2969325/how-to-fix-hyper-v-cluster-error-1196-cluster-name-failed-registration.html) by [Matthew Mombrea](https://www.itworld.com/author/Matthew-Mombrea/):

> The issue, it turns out after days of forehead slapping, is that there were some additional external DNS servers specified on the NIC for that particular node - a remnant of its pre-cluster days. Your cluster node network interfaces should only have DNS records for your internal DNS server. While this didn't cause issues in most cases, for the purpose of cluster network name registration it was wreaking havoc.
>
> First, check the NIC settings for each of your cluster nodes to make sure there are no external DNS records present. If there are, delete them. Next, ensure the A record for your cluster exists on your internal DNS servers in case they have been scavenged.